# URLSessionWebSocketTask - response to ping from server with client pong

Tags: swift, websocket, ping

I use the Apple-provided `URLSessionWebSocketTask` to set up a websocket. I receive, send messages and can send a ping.
But how should I receive and respond to a ping coming from a ws server? I have to work with a server that sends a ping to clients to check if they still are alive.
If I receive something from the server, how can I recognise a ping from that server? Is there some keycode in a received message?

```
func receive() {
    webSocketTask.receive { result in
        print(result)
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to receive message: \(error)")
                ....
        case .success(let message):
            switch message {
            case .data(let data):
                print("\(data)")
                ....
            case .string(let text):
                print("\(text)")
                .....

            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        receive()
    }
}
```

Above is of course a common piece of code, but what should I implement to respond to a ping from the connected server? I did read several docs but couldn't find anything, any pointers or suggestions.

I did found the following OpCode `0x9` and `0xA`. Are those Ping and Pong? Could I send a `0x9` as ping and for pong a `0xA`? If I try this as text message but I get no reaction. Should it be a frame? So what did I do I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It took some digging but you have to set the Opcode to `.pong` in the `NWProtocolWebSocket.Metadata` object which then goes into your `context` parameter in the `NWconnection.send` function. Your data should mirror what was sent in the ping.

```
  let metadata = NWProtocolWebSocket.Metadata(opcode: .pong)
  let context = NWConnection.ContentContext(identifier: "context", metadata: [metadata])
    
  client.send(content: data, contentContext: context, isComplete: true, completion: .contentProcessed({ error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // no-op
        }
    }))
```

client in this case is your `NWConnection`