# How can I detect a server ping using URLSessionWebSocketTask?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, websocket

Using `URLSessionWebSocketTask`, a server ping is automatically responded to by a pong from the client.

Still, can the client observe that a ping/pong occurred?

([a related but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153671/swift5-urlsessionwebsockettask-response-to-ping-from-server-with-client-pong))

Comment: Does the server ping message body contain a timestamp of when it was sent? If yes you can calculate ping from that maybe

Answer (score 0):

Usually, right after setting a connection, you'd need to run ping in a loop in the app:

```swift
  Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 10, runLoop: .main).sink(receiveValue: { _ in
    task.sendPing(pongReceiveHandler: { error in
      guard let error = error else {
        log("Received pong")
        return
      }

      // Handle error
    })
  }).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

UPD:

If you're interested in observing pong, then in subscription, check if you received `0x9` as a data:

```swift
task.receive { result in
  switch result {
  case .success(let message):
    switch message {
    case .data(let data):
      //
    ...
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

It will be:

```swift
close connection: 0x8
ping: 0x9
pong: 0xA
```

So you can create an enum:

```swift
enum Code: UInt8 {
  case closeConnection = 0x8
  case ping = 0x9
  case pong = 0xA
}
```

And initialise it with data you receive: `Code(rawValue: YOURDATA)`

Or you can send "PING" as a text from your cloud server instead, that will simplify things for you

Comment: This is sending a ping from the client. I'm interested in observing pings initiated from the server.

Comment: Got it, updated answer @Guig

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the .data case being hit when receiving a ping from the server. Were you able to observe it?